Understanding: redirect_to @object (typically used within Rails create-action)
From the Ruby on Rails Guides-Tutorial:
def create
  @article = Article.new(title: "...", body: "...")

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article # How does this work?
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

The information concerning "which view to redirect to?": How is it done based upon the @article-object, which is provided here?
I don't get how the mapping is done between "object of a specific class" and specific route.
Is it possible, that Rails does a bit too much magic?

The dynamic resolution of routing helpers is done by ActionDispatch::Routing::PolymorphicRoutes.
What it essentially does here is when you pass a model instance it uses the API provided by ActiveModel::Naming to get the singular route key name:
irb(main):006:0> Article.model_name.singular_route_key
=> "article"

The name is then used to call the article_path route helper method dynamically. Since it's a persisted instance of a model class the polymorphic route helpers will call to_param on the model for the argument to the path helper.
irb(main):007:0> app.polymorphic_path(article)
=> "/articles/3"
irb(main):008:0> app.polymorphic_path(Article.model_name.singular_route_key, [article.to_param])
=> "/articles/3"

This is not just used when redirecting but extensively in other parts of the framework such as forms and links.

Is it possible, that Rails does a bit too much magic?

No.
It's only magic if you don't put the effort in to understand it.
It's just a simple example of using Convention over Configuration to guess the route based on the presumed connection between the models and routes. You don't have to use it.

Well, when I look at it the way it is written there „redirect_to @article“, then for ME it isn’t clear what it will do. Does I become redirected to the show-view or to the index-view? I can only trial-and-error. Anyway: Thanks for your great answer!

The heuristics are very simple. If the record has been saved it will redirect to the member route /articles/1 and if you pass a new record it will give the collection path /articles. Don't think of redirects in terms of what view is rendered - instead just think of it terms of a RESTful API  - are you redirecting to one resource or the whole collection?

Considering it that way helps, indeed. Thanks a lot. :)
